# make gradle dependency task to exclude test dependencies in its result

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew, gradle-dependencies

When i run `./gradlew dependencies` i get whole dependency tree including prod/main and test.

How can i get list of only production/main dependencies in result of **dependencies** task

Official documentation https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html
suggests how to show dependencies that would be required on a specific config, say test runtime classpath in a Java project:

```
`gradle -q dependencies --configuration testRuntimeClasspath`
```

After googling, i found command `gradlew dependencies --configuration compileClasspath`
Will it's result contain runtime dependencies too ?

How can i get list of dependencies, excluding test dependencies in result of dependencies task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want are the "production" runtime dependencies, use `--configuration runtimeClasspath`.

Configurations in Gradle are like buckets of dependencies. The ones contributed by the Java plugin are described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management).

The most interesting ones are these:

- `compileClasspath`: The dependencies needed for compiling a project. Extends extends `compile` (deprecated), `compileOnly` and `implementation`.
- `runtimeClasspath`: The dependencies needed at runtime. Extends `runtime` (deprecated), `runtimeOnly` and `implementation`.

As you noticed, there are also "test" versions of the above two for compiling and running unit tests.